# Problem with Tailwind and Github Pages deployment

Tags: github-actions, tailwind-css, github-pages, astrojs

I'm deploying [this](https://github.com/ferranJS/astro-landing-page) Astro landing page and I have followed Astro's guides to both [integrate Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/astro) and [deploy it to Github Pages](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/deploy/github/) and the page loads with correct HTML but Tailwind classes do not seem to work/load. I cannot find what is missing in the project (maybe some deploy.yml config?) for it to work.
I've built the project locally and the problem is the same

Comment: You seem to be referencing assets – like videos and images – with the root relative `/`, but your site is located at `/astro-landing-page`, so you would need to prepend your paths with `/astro-landing-page`. See https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/configuration-reference/#base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS import in **head** was not getting it right and I don't know what I did but now it loads it well.
Indeed, the media wasn't loading either and I had to add the base to the img and video elements' sources. Thanks to @Wongjn for the insight though.

In my project, you can see the steps to achieve this.